Resources to learn stochastic calculus
I'm looking for a good resource to learn stochastic calculus but I'm not very good at calculus . So could anyone please tell whether the book Stochastic Calculus for Finance by Steven Shreve is a beginner friendly one? if not kindly list out some beginner friendly resources or else tell me the pre req. to learn these.

Check here: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/11096/stochastic-calculus-in-quantitative-analysis

For prerequisite for Stochastic Calculus you need not only Calculus but also some Probability (including the Kolmogorov Axioms and the Normal (also called Gaussian) distribution). Shreve is considered an advanced book, with more extensive prerequisites than most and a more rigorous treatment.

There are several Shreve Books. There is one advanced one you probably are referring to, but also the much more beginner friendly Stochastic calculus for finance II.
